# mysql subqueries keeps repeating

Tags: mysql, database, subquery, repeat

Good Day Everyone, I am having a hard time doing this query where in I needed to List the boat name, owner number, owner last name, and owner first name for each boat in Marina 1.

I have a table of marina_slip [image: marina_slip]
   and marina_owner [image: marina_owner]

I have code of

```
SELECT ms.boat_name, ms.owner_num, o.last_name, o.first_name
FROM marina_slip ms, owner o
WHERE o.owner_num IN(SELECT ms.owner_num FROM marina_slip ms WHERE marina_num = '1');
```

the output is correct but it is repeatinng

query_output

[image: query_output]

Comment: Would you mind editing your question and making some use of the `<>` button above the text box, to format the code?

Comment: hello, thank youu the suggestion. Sorry, I am new here in this community. Still a student.

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots unless someone specifically asks. You've posted a screenshot of a text output, which a) is a lot more effort than just copy/pasting it, b) isn't searchable by search engines and c) can't be copied by us (if we want to set up a test of your problem.  We prefer text pasted, not screenshots of text

Comment: Now, to your problem - specifically speaking your output isn't repeated/containing duplicates. All the rows are unique. Have a read up on "what is a Cartesian product" so you can better understand why it doesn't match what you expect

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an old style join but without the join conditions.
Use a proper join with an ON clause:

```
SELECT ms.boat_name, ms.owner_num, o.last_name, o.first_name
FROM marina_slip ms INNER JOIN owner o
ON o.owner_num = ms.owner_num
WHERE o.owner_num IN (SELECT ms.owner_num FROM marina_slip ms WHERE marina_num = '1');
```

or:

```
SELECT ms.boat_name, ms.owner_num, o.last_name, o.first_name
FROM marina_slip ms INNER JOIN owner o
ON o.owner_num = ms.owner_num
WHERE ms.marina_num = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

We haven't done joins like this for about 30 years:

```
FROM marina_slip ms, owner o
```

Chiefly because it encourages the problem you see now; every row from marina_slip is being combined with every row from owner. There is no *relation* between the tables expressed here. Use the modern join syntax an you won't have a problem:

```
SELECT ms.boat_name, ms.owner_num, o.last_name, o.first_name
FROM 
  marina_slip ms

  --express the relationship between the tables. -> owner num in each table is equal 
  INNER JOIN owner o ON o.owner_num = ms.owner_num

WHERE ms.marina_num = '1';
```

Please [see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins/4480800) or [jeff atwood's coding blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more info on how to use INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOIN syntax

Comment: the syntax I followed is from the book from my university and I think it is outdated.
Thank you for your help folks.

Comment: Yeah, definitely one to complaint to your uni about. What book is it, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

You have no joints between your tables.

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM marina_slip
LEFT JOIN owner ON owner.owner_num=marina_slip.owner_num
WHERE marina_num=1
```

Or, if you want to use your select, add `ms.owner_num=o.owner_num` in your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM marina_slip ms, owner o
WHERE ms.owner_num=o.owner_num
    AND o.owner_num IN(SELECT ms.owner_num FROM marina_slip ms WHERE marina_num = '1');
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=de338afb879d5513a8b281f6ab8e6dfd)

Comment: Why a LEFT JOIN? Does it make any difference?

Comment: With a `INNER JOIN` you only have boat with owner. With `LEFT JOIN` you have all boat even if they don"t have an owner

Comment: All boats have an owner.

Comment: In this case, don't forget to add a foreign key to owner_num into marina_slip table